# ssh-agent installed with git 1.9.5 faults

Tags: windows-7, ssh, git, ssh-agent

I am getting a fault when running ssh-agent from windows 7.
I think it could be a permission issue, though UAC is off.

ssh-agent.exe

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-vDq8tk2Qlatv/agent.10256; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=10996; export SSH_AGENT_PID;tackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to ssh-agent.exe.stackdump
echo Agent pid 10996;
```

The stack dump file looks like this.

```
MSYS-1.0.12 Build:2012-07-05 14:56
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=68064A07
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=7EFDD000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000001
ebp=0028FBFC esp=0028FBD8 program=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh-agent.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028FBFC  68064A07  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 680333C9)
0028FC1C  68062B8A  (0A016010, 00000001, 00000020, 00290000)
0028FC4C  00405D1F  (0A016010, 00000003, 00000002, 00000000)
0028FD4C  00403F59  (00000000, 0A01358C, 0A0103E8, 00000000)
0028FEE8  68004B08  (00000000, 00000000, 0028FF28, 00446B40)
0028FF08  68004C5F  (00403330, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FF28  68004C98  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FF58  00446A48  (00403330, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FF88  0040103D  (7EFDE000, 0028FFD4, 76FF9F72, 7EFDE000)
0028FF94  764A338A  (7EFDE000, 77FB4E17, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FFD4  76FF9F72  (00401000, 7EFDE000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FFEC  76FF9F45  (00401000, 7EFDE000, 00000000, 78746341)
End of stack trace
```

Any suggestions?